# How to do caching if you can't afford misses at all?

Tags: postgresql, caching, redis, event-driven

I'm developing an app that is processing incoming data and currently needs to hit the database for each incoming datapoint. The problem is twofold:

- the database can't keep up with the load
- the database returns results for less than 5% of the queries

The first idea is to cache the data from the relational database into something like Redis to improve lookup speed. But all the regular caching strategies rely on the fact that you can fall back to the database if needed and fetch data from there. This is problematic in my case because for 95% of the queries there is nothing in the database and I don't have anything to store in the cache. I can of course store the empty results in the cache but that would mean that 95% (or even more, depending on the composition of data) of my cache storage would be rubbish.

The preferred way to do it would be to implement a caching system that doesn't have any misses: everything from the database is always present in the cache and therefore if it's not in the cache, then it's not in the database. After looking around though I found that the consistency of Redis does not seem reliable enough to always make that assumption - if the key doesn't exist in Redis, how can I be 100% sure that it doesn't exist in the database (assuming that we're not in the midst of an update)? It is a strong requirement that if there is a row in the database about an incoming datapoint, then it needs to be found and can't just be missed out on.

How do I go about designing a caching system that will always have the same data as the relational database - without having a fallback to look the data up in the database? Redis might not be the tool but what would you recommend? Is there a pattern or a keyword that I should look up that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Sounds like a job for db replication, assuming we are talking about read queries only. Just add more postgres instances. You don't want to use Redis (or any other non-durable db) without fallback. If it restarts then you are screwed.

Comment: You should probably tackle the problem head on, rather than just trying to paper over it with a new layers of problems.  Why is the query too slow?  Maybe auto_explain can help here.

Comment: "assuming that we're not in the midst of an update"  What if you are in the midst or an update?  Does the cache lookup have to block until the update commits or rolls back?  Can it return a dirty hit that might never be committed?  Can it return a miss even though it might change to a hit any nanosecond now?

Comment: Perhaps look into whether a membership sketch, e.g. a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), will fit your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

There already is such a cache in the database: shared buffers. So all you have to do is to set `shared_buffers` big enough to contain the whole database and restart. Soon the whole database will be cached, and reading will cause no more I/O and will be fast.

That also works if you cannot cache the whole database, as long as you only need to access part of it: PostgreSQL will then just cache those 8kB-pages that are in use.

In my opinion, adding another external caching system can never do better than that.  That is particularly true if data are ever modified: any external caching system would have to make sure that its data are not stale, which would introduce an additional overhead.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful and I did think of that. The problem is that the table in question is only a part of a larger database that also has other traffic so buffers wouldn't work wonders here as it wouldn't always have the correct content in memory. We want to cache a relatively small part of a larger database that is getting tons of read traffic.

Comment: If it gets tons of read traffic, it won't drop out of the cache unless the cache is way too small.